# get a MapView from SupportMapFragment

Tags: android

I have an activity_main xml layout which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

can I get in my MainActivity a MapView from this xml layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it like this

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for your answer!
But this is a GoogleMap and not a MapView..
I need to get the MapView.. Is it possible?

Comment: Try it and check if it helps..@user2320431

Comment: I would say @Lal's method is preferred over using a `MapView` directly. The `MapView` docs say: For a simpler method of displaying a Map use MapFragment (or SupportMapFragment) if you are looking to target earlier platforms.